# How to filter multiple categories and show it's posts/articles PHP

Tags: php, mysql, filter, blogs, categories

I have created a page that shows all the posts that are under a **single** category i.e. if i click on the category Music i will get all the Articles that are connected with Music category.

But my goal is to create a filtering option that can filter out certain categories and only show all the posts that are connected to the categories you have filtered i.e. i'll have a bunch of categories with checkboxes behind it and if i check Music and Games and submit the form i want to see all posts under music and games.

Here's the code i'm using to show all posts under 1 single category.

```
<?php require('includes/config.php'); 

$catID = ($_GET['id']);
$catName = ($_GET ['cat']);



?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>XS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <h1>XS <span style="color:blue;"> >> </span> <span><?php echo $catName); ?></span> </h1>

        <hr />

        <div class="grid">

        <?php
            try {
                $stmt = "SELECT * FROM blog_posts NATURAL JOIN blog_posts_categories WHERE catID = $catID";

                $query = $db->prepare($stmt);
                $query->execute();

                $numrows = $query->rowCount();
                if($numrows > 0){

                    while($row = $query->fetch()){
                        echo '<ol class="thumb-grid group">';
                            echo '<li>';
                                echo '<a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">';
                                    echo '<img src="scripts/t.php?src='.$row['postImage'].'&w=236&h=236&q=95" alt="'.$row['postTitle'].'" title="'.$row['postTitle'].'" />';
                                echo '</a>';
                            echo '</li>';
                        echo '</ol>';
                    }

                }

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        ?>


        </div>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

So i started out with the form but it's not quite good since it only sends out the category names and not the corresponding category id.

```
<form action="c.php" method="get">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Filter Categories</legend>
    <p>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="Music"/> Music</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="Games"/> Games</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="Tech"/> Tech</label>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit">Filter</button>
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

***Here´s my database structure:***

**blog_posts** *table*

> **postID** *int, primary, auto increment.*
>
> **postTitle** *varchar*
>
> **postCont** *text*

**blog_categories** *table*

> **catID** *int, primary, auto increment.*
>
> **catName** *varchar*

**blog_posts_categories** *table*

> **postID** *int*
>
> **catID** *int*

---

***Database content:***

**blog_posts**

```
postID  |  postTitle  | postCont

  1          Post1       Cont1
  2          Post2       Cont2
  3          Post3       Cont3
  4          Post4       Cont4
  5          Post5       Cont5
```

**blog_categories**

```
catID   |   catName

  1          Music
  2          Games
  3        Technology
```

**blog_posts_categories**

```
postID  |  catID

  1          1
  1          2
  1          3
  2          2
  3          3
  4          1
  4          2
  5          2
  5          3
```

Comment: You are echoing out the imploded $links. Could you edit your post and show us what is echoed out and what is the generated query you have tried to run?

Comment: i did that on purpose just to test and never removed it actually. The code now only selects 1 category id and shows all the posts that are connected to that 1 category. What I like to achieve is to filter multiple categories in order to show all posts that are connected to those categories you have filtered.

Comment: If you have a catIDs list, what does prevent you from running something like this: "SELECT * FROM blog_posts NATURAL JOIN blog_posts_categories WHERE catID in (".implode(",", $catIDs).")"  ?

Answer (score 2):

#### The form content

Replace your checkboxes values with the actual category id, and put the category name in the tag inner text content:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="<?php echo $row['catID'];?>"/><?php echo $row['catName'];?></input>
```

You can get that data out of the DB (the `blog_categories` table) and do a simple loop on the rows of the result set.

#### The table display

Now you should get an array in  `$_GET["cat"]` of all the selected category ids; you just need to implode it with comma as a separator, and put it in your query, replacing `WHERE catID = $catID"` with `WHERE catID IN ($catID)"`. Don't forget to sanitize your request data first (by checking that the values are integers).

Lastly, you might want to update your table display by adding the category the post belongs to in an extra column, or sort your data by category, and have sub tables for each category. This is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php 
      $query = "SELECT * FROM `name` WHERE `status` = '1' ";
      if(isset($_GET['catname'])){
          $cat1 = $_GET['catname'];
        $query .= " AND `category` = '$cat1' ";
      }
      $query .= " ORDER BY `ptid` DESC ";

      $result = mysql_query($query);
      $nums = mysql_num_rows($result);
      if($nums > 0){
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_row($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
          $ptid_dec = $rows['ptid'];
          $mult = '987694929';
          $ptid = $ptid_dec*$mult;
          $productname = $rows['productname'];
          $productimage = $rows['productimage'];
          $description = $rows['description'];
   ?>

        <?php echo $productimage; ?>" 
        <div class="caption">
          <a href="admin/<?php echo $productimage; ?>" target="_blank"><h4 class="center listdesign"><strong><?php echo $productname; ?></strong></h4></a>


    <?php } } ?>
```

Comment: Use table for above Query

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$("#example1").DataTable({
  "pageLength": 9,
  "lengthChange": false,
  "bFilter": false,
  "bInfo": false,
  "bAutoWidth": false
});
$('#example2').DataTable({
  "paging": true,
  "lengthChange": false,
  "searching": false,
  "ordering": true,
  "info": true,
  "autoWidth": false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <script>
 function paginateScroll() {
$('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $(".topheader").offset().top
}, 100);
console.log('pagination button clicked'); //remove after test
$(".paginate_button").unbind('click', paginateScroll);
$(".paginate_button").bind('click', paginateScroll);
}
paginateScroll();  
</script>
```